# Is there a standard for REST database connectivity?

Tags: database, rest, jdbc, odbc

Is there a standard for REST database connectivity, or anyone hearing any whiffs of a plan? A standard similar to JDBC or ODBC for REST?

I am not asking about some people who have in-house impl of JDBC over HTTP REST.

Let me illustrate ...
e.g.,

```
http: // dataserver:5200/{instance}/{schema}
Accept: application/xml
Encoding: utf-8
Authorization: blah blah
Querystring: select * from hello where id>100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Open Data Protocol: http://www.odata.org/

Answer (score -1):

REST is a buzzword. The back-end implementation can be pretty much anything, including hiring an army of slaves to perform the "database" operations and another army of slaves to type up the results. REST is concerned with specifying how a remote client can interface with a server, not how the server goes about its job of actually satisfying the clients' requests.

Comment: O c'mon. XML is a buzzword, and you can pretty do anything about it. But somehow, people have come together to agree to a single set of "protocols" like HL7, xsd, etc. Just standardising, very primitive unexciting but extremely helpful non-technology.